# Spline over a cylinder

Tags: matlab, plot, spline

I am trying to dray the blue line on the image below on matlab based on the geometry of the t-joint. I use coordinate iteration and spline fct to do so. I don't know why but I can't get it to work properly. Can you enlight me ?

Thanks,

[image]

clear all;
    clc;

```
%Defining Graph size
x = -D/2:((D/2)+l2);
y = -l1/2 :l1/2;
z = -D/2: D/2;

%Variable Definition
r = D/2;


%Winding step one

for y=-r-l2:0.01:0;
    x = -(r+l2)/r;
    z = sqrt(r.^2-x.^2);
    xyz = [x ; y ; z];
    %can be erased to remove points
    fnplt(cscvn(xyz(:,[1:end 1])),'r',2);
    hold on;
    end

    %Axis Labeling
xlabel('X Axis','FontSize',14);
ylabel('Y Axis','FontSize',14);
zlabel('Z Axis','FontSize',14);
title('Tjoint winding w/o radii','FontSize',14);
```

Comment: I assume the initial lines asking for input are unrelated to your problem. Please replace them with some constants. This prevents anyone from causing additional problems choosing wrong parameters.

Comment: "I don't know why but I can't get it to work properly. " What is not working? Does the code run? Does it give output? Is the output correct or not? How do you know? Your question is very hard to answer without this important information.

Comment: Hi David, 
sorry to not be clear enough. the problem seems to be at 
z = sqrt(r.^2-x.^2);

I get the warning :
Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X, Y, and/or Z arguments ignored 
> In fnplt at 237
  In Twinding_revb at 37 (line 37 is fnplt(cscvn(xyz(:,[1:end 1])),'r',2);)

I don't understand why, it seems to be an error in my equations, but I don't see my mistake.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my error by myself after a good night of sleep and it was pretty obviousl I simply made an error regarding the equations I used. Here the corrected code if it can be useful to someone.

```
  clear all;
clc;
%TJoint Winding w/o radius
%The idea is to experiment with matlab 

%Obtains the values 
D = 'What is the diameter of the t joint? ';
D = input(D);

l1 = 'What is the length 1 of the t joint? ';
l1 = input(l1);

l2 = 'What is the length 2 of the t joint? ';
l2 = input(l2);

w = 'What is the width of the carbon fiber used? ';
w = input(w);

'Thank you, we are now processing the Filament winding of your T-Joint. Please wait ';

%Defining Graph size
x = -l1/2 :l1/2;
y = -D/2:((D/2)+l2);
z = -D/2: D/2;

%Variable Definition
r = D/2;


%Winding step one

for y=-r-l2:0.01:0;
    x = (-r/(r+l2))*y ;
    z = sqrt(r.^2-x.^2);
    xyz = [x ; y ; z];
    %can be erased to remove points
    fnplt(cscvn(xyz(:,[1:end 1])),'r',2);
    hold on;
    end

    %Axis Labeling
xlabel('X Axis','FontSize',14);
ylabel('Y Axis','FontSize',14);
zlabel('Z Axis','FontSize',14);
title('Tjoint winding w/o radii','FontSize',14);
```